# Maintenance page still "Beta"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I've seen yesterday that our maintenance page is still the maintenance page of beta sites.

Do we need materials to build one? or has it just been forgotten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was *almost* done when the site was themed, but lacked one last step.  When we update the offline pages, they have to be *completely* static and served by our load balancer (HAProxy)...which simply has an old copy that doesn't have security and bicycles site themes in there yet.

We'll get an update pushed today or tomorrow so you'll see a pretty page next time!